# Passing a Variable to Meteor's Observe

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I am using Meteor's `.observe` function to add new data points to a chart as soon as new records appear in the query being observed.

```
Pressure.find().observe({
    added: function(id, fields) {
        self.chart.addPoints(fields.value)
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to get the variable `chart` to be passed into the `added` callback function of `.observe`. It will be undefined whenever the `added` callback function is triggered.

Any help to pass `chart` into the `added` callback function will help greatly! Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export class PressureChart extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.startObserver()
    }

    startObserver() {
        this.chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
        var self = this;

        this.observer = Pressure.find().observe({
            added: function(id, fields) {
                console.log(self.chart)
                self.chart.addPoints(fields.value)
            }
        })
    }

    render() { // ... }
}



export default createContainer(() => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('pressure');
    const handleReady = handle.ready() 

    return {
        pressure: handleReady ? Pressure.find().fetch() : [],
    }
}, PressureChart);
```

Comment: Does this.refs.chart.getChart() give you something that's not undefined?

Comment: @zim this.refs.chart.getChart() is `a.chart{ ...something inside }`. But it becomes an empty chart object `a.chart{}` inside the added callback function of Pressure.find().observe

Comment: weird. sorry, i don't see what's wrong.

Comment: @zim figured it to be a bug with the react port of the library.... any recommendations of JS library to use for realtime streaming plots?